# Instance of one class to contain arbitrary number of instances of another class in Python

Tags: python, object-oriented, design-patterns

I'm trying to see if there is a better way to design this. I have a class Animal that is inherited by Male and Female classes (Female class has an additional attribute). I also have a class called Habitat, an instance of each would contain any number of Animals including 0.

```
class Animal:

    def __init__(self, life_span=20, age=0):
        self.__life_span = life_span
        self.__age = age

    def get_life_span(self):
        return self.__life_span

    def get_age(self):
        return self.__age

    def age(self):
        self.__age += 1


class Female(Animal):

    __gender = 'female'

    def __init__(self, pregnant=False):
        self.__pregnant = pregnant

    def impregnate(self):
        self.__pregnant = True


class Male(Animal):

    __gender = 'male'


class Habitat:

    def __init__(self, list_of_animals=[Male(), Female()]): 
        self.__list_of_animals = list_of_animals

    def __add_male(self):
        self.__list_of_animals.append(Male())

    def __add_female(self):
        self.__list_of_animals.append(Female())

    def add_animal(self):
        if random.choice('mf') == 'm':
            self.__add_male()
        else:
            self.__add_female()    

    def get_population(self):
        return self.__list_of_animals.__len__()
```

Before I add any more functionality, I would like to find out if that's a proper way to design these classes. Maybe there is a design pattern I can use? I'm new to OOP, any other comments/suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: FWIW, don't call `obj.__len__()`, use `len(obj)` instead. Also, no need to use name mangling (double leading underscores): Just use `self.age` or `self._age`, especially use the former in favor of trivial getters (you can later replace them with a `property`, *if* you need that extra power, without changing the way client code works with your objects).

Comment: It would appear you're new to OOP in general - what's your experience?

Comment: @tallseth: already flagged as such. OP: if the moderators agree, your question will be automatically migrated for you. Please do not double-post.

Comment: @JonClements somehow I managed to avoid the whole thing and it's been bugging me for years, so now I'm trying to get a grip of it

Comment: @MartijnPieters thanks, can I do it myself without waiting for moderators?

Comment: Good first attempt - but IMHO - not correct - an Animal is either Male or Female (possibly both given some species), no need to subclass a Gender

Comment: @dfo: No, you can't. It is a moderator-level descision I'm afraid.

Answer (score 4):

In `Habitat.__init__`, you've committed a classic beginner's fallacy: using a list as a default argument.

In Python, every call to a function with a default argument will use the same default object. If that object is mutable (e.g. a list) any mutations to that object (e.g. `.append`) will affect that one object. In effect, all your `Habitat`s will end up using the exact same list unless you specify a non-default argument.

Instead, use `None` as the default argument, and test for it:

```
def __init__(self, animals=None):
    if animals is None:
        animals = [Male(), Female()]
```